# Declaring variables with template defined type

Tags: c++, class, templates, compiler-errors

```
template <class T>
void foo(T arg) {
    T var = arg;
}
```

Is this possible? I have a similar situation and I can't get something like this to work.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are trying to instanciate a T it'll work. But if you try to instanciate a T::iterator, or a T::your_random_typedef, it won't. You need to use 'typename T::your_random_typedef my_variable;' if you want to declare one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, the above works fine, as this minimal compilable example shows:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T arg)
{
    T var = arg;
}

int main()
{
    foo(23);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem must be in other code you haven't posted yet :)

Comment: Thanks, I figured the problem would be elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible and will work if T is copyable.
It may not work for if T is a class that has a private copy constructor:

```
class Noncopyable {
private:
    Noncopyable(const Noncopyable&);

public:
    Noncopyable() {}
};

template <class T>
void foo(T arg) {
    T var = arg;
}

int main()
{
    foo(Noncopyable());
}
```